# Android Device not showing under target, but does show in device manager

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an app on Android, which was always easy. Now I try to connect my android tablet (Sony Xperia Z2 tablet) or my phone (Sony Xperia Z) both running on Android KitKat. They both show up under the Devices in Eclipse. (I think adb is working then?!). However when I try to launch an app the tablet and phone don't show up under target. I can run old projects that once have runned, but even then the device is not in the list, I can only press ok and it runs.

I am using Mac OsX Yosemite with Eclipse Juno (downloaden from the developer site of Android).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Wouter

Comment: I have found the problem. Apperently the sdk version of the tablet cannot be read from Eclipse. Under run configurations (right click --> run as --> run configurations) set under target launch on all connected devices. The the problem is solved. Took me forever to find this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined maxSdkVersion in the manifest? If so, the try removing it or setting it to 19 or higher.